# Question about calculating electric susceptibility as a function of temperature

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

I am trying to calculate the electric susceptibility as temperature changes. From a textbook, [1], the equation is: $$\chi (\omega) = \frac{Ng_2A_{21}\pi c^3}{g_1\omega_0^3}\left\{\frac{1}{\omega_0 -\omega -iA_{21}/2}+\frac{1}{\omega_0 +\omega +iA_{21}/2} \right\}$$
But none of those quantities are dependent on temperature. The Einstein $A$ coefficient is temperature independent. There is a paper [2], which does a similar thing and uses the equation:
$$\chi (\omega) = 2N_mc^2\sum_l\frac{S_{ml}}{\omega_{0ml}}\left\{\frac{1}{\omega +\omega_{0ml} -i\Gamma_{ml}/2}-\frac{1}{\omega -\omega_{0ml} -i\Gamma_{ml}/2} \right\}$$
where $m$ are the different molecules and they are summing over all transitions $l$. Where they are getting $S$, the line intensity, from [3]:
$$S_{ij} = I_a \frac{A_{ij}}{8\pi c \nu_{ij}^2} \frac{g_i \exp\left(-\frac{hcE_j}{kT}\right)\left[ 1 - \exp\left(-\frac{hc\nu_{ij}}{kT} \right)\right]}{Q(T)}$$
and $$ Q(T)=\sum_k g_k \exp\left(-\frac{hcE_k}{kT} \right) $$
So the equation in [2] is dependent on temperature. But the problem is that the two equations for $\chi$ are different from each other. You would think that the 2nd equation from the paper [2] would match up with the first equation at some reference temperature, which is given as 296 K in [3]. But that isnt the case. So what I am wondering is, is the second equation for $\chi$ given in [2] actually incorrect? Or is the text book version over simplified and missing some factor that is dependent on temperature but is usually neglected?

Does anyone have experience working with the HITRAN database for calculating electric susceptibility as a function of temperature?

[1] Loudon, R. The Quantum Theory of Light. 2003 p. 63.

[2] Mathar, R. J. 2007 *J. Opt. A: Pure Appl. Opt.* **9** 470.

[3] HITRAN Online. https://hitran.org/docs/definitions-and-units/#ref5